# Asymptotic behaviour / Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Let $0<\omega<\infty, \mu >0$ and $z \in \mathbb{R}.$ In my book, it is written that we have the following asymptotic behaviour:

> i) Claim: $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{z \omega}{\sqrt{t \mu}}=0.$$
>   ii) Claim:  $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{z \omega}{\mu} \sqrt{\frac{t}{\mu}}+\frac{t}{\mu} \right)=\infty.$$

Can I proof it like that?

i) $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{z \omega}{\sqrt{t \mu}}= \frac{z \omega}{\sqrt{ \mu}} \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t^{1/2} }=0,$$
since $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t^n} =0$ for $n>0.$

ii) $$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{z \omega}{\mu} \sqrt{\frac{t}{\mu}}+\frac{t}{\mu} \right)=\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{z \omega}{\mu} \sqrt{\frac{t}{\mu}}+ \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{t}{\mu} = \frac{z \omega}{\mu} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\mu}} \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}  \sqrt{t}+ \frac{1}{\mu} \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} t=\infty.$$

Comment: $ \lim_{t \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{t^n} = 0; \forall n \gt 0 $

Comment: I added it in my post. But can I really do it so easy?

Comment: For the second one, no, since you would end up with $-\infty + \infty$ if $z < 0$.  What you wrote is fine for when $z > 0$ though.